# Using Bubble Sort

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I want to create a program which sorts the array using the bubble sort technique,but only the first iteration happens. I need help understanding why this is happening.

```
a=[10,4,5,2,0,6]
def srt(element):
    element1=element[:]
    element2=element[:]
    idx=1
    for x in element:
        for y in element2[idx:]:
             if x>y:
                element1[idx]=x
                element1[idx-1]=y
                print(element1)
                idx+=1
             else:
                pass
```

I want to show all steps of the sort

Comment: can we see what you're passing into the function?

Comment: are you sure even the first iteration is happening? the code you've written here only "defines" the function, you never call it.

Comment: By the way, part of the reason you're being downvoted is that your question title isn't descriptive of the question you're asking.

Comment: x=srt(a)
here it is

Comment: The code you posted is not a bubble sort -- there are thousands of examples on line; we expect you to do that research before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is semantically wrong. You're not comparing adjacent elements.

your code...

```
for x in element:
            for y in element2[idx:]:
                 if x>y:
```

will compare the first element of the list with every other element in the list beginning at idx.

Bubble sort works by comparing adjacent elements and "bubbling" the greatest/least element to the end of the list on each pass.

This code found on interactivepython.org works by iterating from the beginning of the list to `(len of list) - (number of iterations)` so on the first pass it bubbles the greatest element to the end of the list. On the second pass it bubbles the second greatest element to the second to last position in the list... and so on.

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp
```

https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBubbleSort.html